# Sails.js: can't find variable require (react-bootstrap-datetimepicker)

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, module, reactjs, sails.js

I'm using Sails js and I want to use a nodejs module.
I also use React js.
I want to use `react-bootstrap-datetimepicker` in my javascript script.
[react-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/quri/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker)
I installed my module with `npm install react-bootstrap-datetimepicker`

I tried in `config/boostrap.js` to add this line `var DateTimeField = require('react-bootstrap-datetimepicker');`, but DateTimeField isn't recognised in my js script.
`Uncaught ReferenceError: DateTimeField is not defined`

I also tried to add this line directly in my script, but I have this error:
`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require`

And also this one in my script: `import DateTimeField from "react-bootstrap-datetimepicker";`

I have all these errors in the navigator console.

**EDIT 1:**

I understand what you said, thank you for your answer.
BUT, for example with [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html), I can use:

`var Input = ReactBootstrap.Input;
var ButtonInput = ReactBootstrap.ButtonInput;`

There is exactly the same architecture with react-bootstrap-datetimepicker,  so I maybe I can do the same?
`var DateTimePicker = ... . DateTimePicker`
I tried to include like you said, but it doesn't recognise DateTimePicker.

*Here is the doc:* 
Installation :
`npm install react-bootstrap-datetimepicker`

Then
javascript
`var DateTimeField = require('react-bootstrap-datetimepicker');`

```
render: function() {
  return <DateTimeField />;
}
```

See (examples/) for more details.

And in [examples](https://github.com/quri/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/master/examples/basic/basic.js)/, the line is:

```
import DateTimeField from "react-bootstrap-datetimepicker";
```

Comment: You mean, you want to use react-bootstrap-datetimepicker server side side(which i don't see the point) or client side?

Comment: I want to use client side, in order to have a date time picker in a form :)

Comment: ReactBootstrap is a global in your example... I'm not sure if you are implying that you are already using require or import with react and react bootstrap, if you are, is because you are using browserify and/or babel, if you are not, then honestly i have no idea how are you doing it

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first you have to understand the division of server side and client side javascript, even thought you are using the same language, and you can share libraries, bare in mind, that for client side js you need to supply the user browser with the libraries and scripts it needs, so those have to be in the html you serve the user. When you require any module in sails bootstrap or similar, you are loading the script into the server memory, not serving it to the users browser, that means you can use in the server code, but not in client code.

For you use case, you have to **download the [library code](https://github.com/quri/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/master/dist/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js)**, and put it in your **assets/js** folder and if you have the script tags in the layout, sails will automatically inject it there for you, but if not or you are using other template engine like jade, just manually add it.

example:

```
<html>
  ....
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/<react-version>/react.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/<react-version>/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/<version>/react-bootstrap.min.js">
  <script src='/js/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js'></script>
  // The other js files that depend on datetimepicker go here
</html>
```

Now just to be clear, `require` is a node.js function, node.js is not the same as javascript, its a piece of software with its own functions, thats why you are getting an error related to it when trying to use it in the browser, there is no require method there, so you can't use it, at least not directly. You can use [browserify](http://browserify.org/) to sort of emulate the node workflow, where you have a node_modules folder and use require on those, browserify will bundle (search for the modules and merge them) and give you a javascript file that you can then link in your html code. That is more setup work, and unless you really need it, because you have a lot of files, i think is not worth the effort.. lets say for just one file using require.
So i think you were misguided by that github repo, because it says npm-install. Just ignore it (unless you use browsefify like i said) and download the link i gave you above ( the .min.js).

**So to sumarize, you issue have nothing to do with sails, just link the library in the html you provide to the user, like any other client side script.**

Comment: As i said, if you want to use require, you need browserify, if you are already using it, then it should work or you should make another question. If you check https://github.com/quri/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/master/package.json they are using browserify, bower for dependencies (npm style), and babel to transpile from es6 code, if you are not using all of that, its impossible to work.